Viscosity solution $u$ and the equation of $e^t u$
The function $u_0$ is called the viscosity subsolution of the equation
$$\partial_t u+\Delta u=0$$
with $u(x,0)=u^*(x)$ if for any $(x_0,t_0)\in\mathbb{R}^d\times[0,T]$ and any test function $\varphi \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d\times[0,T])$ such that $u_0-\varphi$ attains a maximum at $(x_0,t_0)$, then $\partial_t \varphi+\Delta \varphi\geq0$ and $u_0(x,0)\leq u^*(x)$. How can we prove that $e^t u_0$ is the viscosity subsolution of the equation
$$\partial_t u+\Delta u-u=0?$$
The definition of viscosity subsolution of this equation is defined in the same way as before ($\partial_t \varphi+\Delta \varphi-\varphi\geq0$).

You defined the viscosity subsolution of the first equation. How do you define the viscosity subsolution of the last equation?

It is defined in the same way.

Keep in mind you only replace derivatives of $u$ by the test function, not the function $u$ itself. So the $-u$ term remains.

@Jeff, do you mean that the definition of subsolution of the second is not correct? It should be $\partial_t \varphi +\Delta \varphi -u \geq 0$?

Yes. It has to be this way, since if $\phi$ is a valid test function then so is $\phi+C$ for any constant $C$ (i.e., $u-\phi - C$ still attains a max at $(x_0,t_0)$).
